# Why does org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.navigate().to() not wait after first three loops?

Tags: java, selenium

When I run the following program...

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.util.*;

class GoogleSearch {

    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    static ArrayList<String> hitUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk/");
            submitSearch("selenium");
            loopHits();
        }

        finally {
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    static void submitSearch(String search) throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys(search);
        searchBox.submit();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    static void loopHits() {
        List<WebElement> hits = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3/a"));

        for (WebElement element: hits) {
            hitUrls.add(element.getAttribute("href"));
        }

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (String url: hitUrls) {
            System.out.println(url);
            driver.navigate().to(url);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time1);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following printed to the console:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/
1136
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Selenium-HealthProfessional/
3476
http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/lifestyle-guide-11/supplement-guide-selenium
6468
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium
6515
http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?dbid=95&tname=nutrient
6550
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-5009/How-diseases-selenium-beat.html
6574
http://www.webmd.boots.com/vitamins-and-minerals/selenium
6592
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium
6623
http://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/minerals/selenium
6645
https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/
6671

Why does the program wait for the first three pages to load but not for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver is not waiting because you are not giving it a reason to wait.

To have it wait for each page to load you need to simulate some action (e.g. find something on the page)

This can be accomplished by asking for the source of each page:

As an example, you can get the page source in your `loopHits()` method:

```
static void loopHits()
{
    List<WebElement> hits = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3/a"));

    for (WebElement element : hits)
    {
        hitUrls.add(element.getAttribute("href"));
    }

    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (String url : hitUrls)
    {
        System.out.println(url);
        driver.navigate().to(url);

        // ask for the page source...
        driver.getPageSource();

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time1);
    }
}
```

Running on my machine, I can see the time diffs spaced out like below:

```
http://www.seleniumhq.org/
1573
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Selenium-HealthProfessional/
5173
http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/lifestyle-guide-11/supplement-guide-selenium
10824
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium
12613
http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?dbid=95&tname=nutrient
14239
http://www.webmd.boots.com/vitamins-and-minerals/selenium
16065
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-5009/How-diseases-selenium-beat.html
23928
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium
26697
https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/
29079
http://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/minerals/selenium
33409
https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=CCSnbNaVEV4e-DZKDpgO6hoyoDc279rVE57yLrG_K9PgECAMQAWDJBqABlfnw9QPIAQGqBCVP0IoUF49U6i-W-LSbFn4urqTiQ8cVwVGqxLuw9CLUSmLBJaUzgAfTho8KkAcDqAemvhvYBwE&sig=AOD64_3aOSd8gM4Vt4iAkp8jHXbgzAv7JQ&clui=0&q=&ved=0ahUKEwiB5_mOs_PMAhUDeFIKHTtiDG0Q0QwIfA&adurl=http://clickserve.dartsearch.net/link/click%3Flid%3D43700001249650557%26ds_s_kwgid%3D58700000142442718%26%26ds_e_adid%3D29839647511%26ds_e_matchtype%3Dsearch%26ds_e_device%3Dc%26ds_e_network%3Dg%26%26ds_url_v%3D2%26ds_dest_url%3Dhttp://www.puritan.com/selenium-078%3Fscid%3D6831%26cmp%3Dgoo-_-MineralSelenium-_-selenium
41033
http://www.puritan.com/selenium-078?scid=6831&cmp=goo-_-MineralSelenium-_-selenium100mg
43442
```

Comment: Thank you Michael Markidis, that solves it. I'm still baffled as to why the program finds reason to wait for the first three pages though..?

Comment: Your welcome. I don't believe it actually is waiting for the first 3. My guess is that it's probably some operational/timing thing that is just giving the illusion that it is waiting for the first 3. You could try to run some tests if you are interested. For example, you can have you code do multiple google searches within one run and see what's happening to the first 3 results of each google search invocation.